Install and run Bitcoin Core on Linux Mint 22
I need help installing Bitcoin Core with Linux Mint 22
Everything I have tried produces an error.
I have Linux Mint 22 on a laptop.  There is a 1TB external SSD freshly formatted.  In the Downloads directory there are 2 files.
/home/james/Downloads/bitcoin-27.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
and
/home/james/Downloads/bitcoin-27.0
Did running the tar.gz file install the second one, bitcoin-27.0?
Please advise and recommend the most complete and detailed instructions for a Linux novice.

/home/james/Downloads/bitcoin-27.0 makes me think you successfully extracted .tar.gz file. In that folder when you run the Bitcoin application, which errors are you getting?
